# Node id of tree isnt getting published

Tags: dojo, dijit.tree

I am trying to publish a node id**(coming from my rest services)** as per the below approach. First I am setting the value for nodeID and then I am passing it through var message to publishing it on check-box click of my dijit tree. I am able to get value stored in node id but when I put an alert on the message variable I don't obtain any result. Only object[object] gets returned . Can someone suggest where am I going wrong here? Why am I not getting the node id from message which I am trying to publish?

```
   onclick:function(item){
    var nodeID = id,  
        var message = 
        {
        sender: this,
        group: 'default',
        itemIds: nodeID
         };
        alert(message);
        dojo.publish("/checkbox/select", [message]);}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is solved we need to access the individual items as message.itemids